# Category specific months list in sidebar.php

Tags: sidebar, archives

What have made me pulling my hair apart for while, how to output category specific month list. I've been searching for the same problem and solution cannot find any lucky so far...

Anyway, I have two POST type pages in my web site. 
One is NEWS page(ex. `http://example.com/news/`) and the other is BLOG page(ex. `http://example.com/blog/`).

I use `archive.php` to show my NEWS and BLOG page and where I want to output month list with post counts in `sidebar.php`.
I could output lists by using `wp_get_archives('cat=0')`
however this outputs like this

```
2013/05(20)
2013/06(12)
2013/07(18)
2013/08(6)
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/2013/05/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/2013/06/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/2013/07/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/2013/08/"></a></li>
```

When I click one of these, this takes me to the page where all the posts happened in that specific month, of course.

What I'd like to output if I am in NEWS page for example is:

HTML:

```
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/news/2013/05/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/news/2013/06/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/news/2013/07/"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://xxxxxxxx.com/wp/news/2013/08/"></a></li>
```

Category specific.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `getarchives_where` filter to get archives by category

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'my_archives_filter_function', 10, 2 );

// your filter function replace YOUR CATEGORY ID with category term id e.g(3)
function my_archives_filter_function($where) {
   global $wpdb;
   $where ." AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 'YOUR CATEGORY ID')";
   return $where;
}
```

now call `wp_get_archives();`

Comment: thanks @Anjum I am bit new to WP. So what I gotta do is just copy & paste your code into my `sidebar.php`, right? It doesn't seem working so far...

Comment: Try functions.php

Comment: Won't this affect all archive pages? I thought the question asked was how to create a date archive page for each category on the site...